# SQL Query fails using mysql-2-async but will work using data grip

Tags: sql, mysql

When I try to insert data into mysql database using mysql-2 in nextjs it fails, if i copy the sql from the error and enter it manually using datagrip IDE it does not fail:

Error Code:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
> 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS new_plant; 
> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_plant AS ( SELECT ...' at line 1
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at async Db.getrow (C:\Users\98max\WebstormProjects\13_DGT_WEBSITE\website\node_modules\mysql2-async\lib\index.js:49:25)
> at async makeQuery (webpack-internal:///(api)/./src/lib/databse.ts:182:20)
> at async handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./src/pages/api/plants/upload.ts:375:22)
> at async Object.apiResolver (C:\Users\98max\WebstormProjects\13_DGT_WEBSITE\website\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils\node.js:372:9)
> at async DevServer.runApi (C:\Users\98max\WebstormProjects\13_DGT_WEBSITE\website\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:514:9)
> at async Object.fn (C:\Users\98max\WebstormProjects\13_DGT_WEBSITE\website\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:828:35)
> at async Router.execute (C:\Users\98max\WebstormProjects\13_DGT_WEBSITE\website\node_modules\next\dist\server\router.js:243:32)
> at async DevServer.runImpl (C:\Users\98max\WebstormProjects\13_DGT_WEBSITE\website\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:432:29)
> at async DevServer.run (C:\Users\98max\WebstormProjects\13_DGT_WEBSITE\website\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:831:20)
> at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (C:\Users\98max\WebstormProjects\13_DGT_WEBSITE\website\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:375:20)
> at async C:\Users\98max\WebstormProjects\13_DGT_WEBSITE\website\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:157:99 {
>
> code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
> errno: 1064,
>
>   sql:
>
> `INSERT INTO plants ( preferred_name, english_name, maori_name, latin_name, location_found, small_description, long_description, author, last_modified) VALUES ( 'Moari', 'Test Plant????', 'SQL Gonna work :))', 'Reckon there will be an error?', 'Coastal', 'eftedfggd', '<p>dfdfdfgssg</p>', 'Max Tyson', FROM_UNIXTIME(1687954736650 / 1000.0)) ;<br>DROP TABLE IF EXISTS new_plant; <br>CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_plant AS <br>( SELECT id FROM plants ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ); SELECT id FROM new_plant;<br>INSERT INTO months_ready_for_use (plant_id, months_event, months_start_month, months_end_month) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM new_plant), '45', 'March', 'February');<br>INSERT INTO edible (plant_id, edible_part_of_plant, edible_image, edible_nutrition, edible_preparation, edible_preparation_type) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM new_plant), 'Heart', 'Plants r 5GB now???', 'null', '<p>hgf</p>', 'Boiled'), ((SELECT id FROM new_plant), 'Leaf', 'Plants r 5GB now???', 'null', '<p>34345</p>', 'Cooked');<br>INSERT INTO medical (plant_id, medical_type, medical_use, medical_image, medical_preparation) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM new_plant), 'External', '<p>333</p>', 'SD is a plant????', '<p>5555</p>');<br>INSERT INTO craft (plant_id, craft_part_of_plant, craft_use, craft_image, craft_additional_info) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM new_plant), 'Heart', '<p>345</p>', 'Plants r 5GB now???', '<p>743</p>')<br>;INSERT INTO source (plant_id, source_type, source_data) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM new_plant), 'Person', 'Maxy Moo');<br>INSERT INTO custom (plant_id, custom_title, custom_text) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM new_plant), 'Histoty """', '<p><strong>BOLD</strong></p>');INSERT INTO attachments (plant_id, attachments_path, attachments_type, attachments_meta, attachments_downloadable) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM new_plant), 'Colorful Flat Your Opinion Matters Instagram Post.png', 'image', '{"name":"Plants r 5GB now???","credits":"google.com","tags":[""]}', false), ((SELECT id FROM new_plant), 'main_bg.jpg', 'image', '{"name":"SD is a plant????","credits":"44","tags":[""]}', false);`,
> sqlState: '42000',
> sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
> 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS new_plant; 
> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_plant AS ( SELECT ...' at line 1",
> clientstack: "Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
>  'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS new_plant; 
> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_plant AS ( SELECT ...' at line 1\n" +
> '    at PromisePool.query (C:\Users\98max\WebstormProjects\13_DGT_WEBSITE\website\node_modules\mysql2-async\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:341:22)\n' +
> '    at Db.query (C:\Users\98max\WebstormProjects\13_DGT_WEBSITE\website\node_modules\mysql2-async\lib\index.js:29:57)\n' +
> '    at Db.getrow (C:\Users\98max\WebstormProjects\13_DGT_WEBSITE\website\node_modules\mysql2-async\lib\index.js:49:36)\n' +
> '    at makeQuery (webpack-internal:///(api)/./src/lib/databse.ts:182:33)\n' +
> '    at handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./src/pages/api/plants/upload.ts:375:83)\n' +
> '    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n' +
> '    at async Object.apiResolver (C:\Users\98max\WebstormProjects\13_DGT_WEBSITE\website\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils\node.js:372:9)\n' +
> '    at async DevServer.runApi (C:\Users\98max\WebstormProjects\13_DGT_WEBSITE\website\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:514:9)\n' +
> '    at async Object.fn (C:\Users\98max\WebstormProjects\13_DGT_WEBSITE\website\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:828:35)\n' +
> '    at async Router.execute (C:\Users\98max\WebstormProjects\13_DGT_WEBSITE\website\node_modules\next\dist\server\router.js:243:32)\n' +
> '    at async DevServer.runImpl (C:\Users\98max\WebstormProjects\13_DGT_WEBSITE\website\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:432:29)\n' +
> '    at async DevServer.run (C:\Users\98max\WebstormProjects\13_DGT_WEBSITE\website\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:831:20)\n' +
> '    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (C:\Users\98max\WebstormProjects\13_DGT_WEBSITE\website\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:375:20)\n' +
> '    at async C:\Users\98max\WebstormProjects\13_DGT_WEBSITE\website\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:157:99'
> }
> DATA
> null

Source code: https://github.com/maxtyson123/13_DGT_WEBSITE

I tried using escape functions and they didnt work. I tried entering the SQL manually

Comment: Do you think that is actually readable? Do you think anyonw will bother to try and read that? [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to format my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Looks like you are trying to execute more than one query within the same call. Is that legal or do you need to set a parameter in order to do that like in node.js